# Accessing downloads folder in android to get URI of file (API 33)

Tags: java, android, apk, android-permissions, android-storage

i would just like to know if its possible to access the downloads folder to get a URI of a file there. As of API30, i understand scoped storage was introduced but is there any workaround or way to access apk files in the **Download** folder?.
I know using storage access framework (SAF) allows this but it requires user interaction to select the file. I am curious if it is possible that upon a broadcast receiver, i can get the uri of a apk file in the downloads folder.I am developing on api 33

Comment: No. For 30+ you need to use SAF and let the user select the file if your app did not create that file. All has nothing to do with scoped storage.

Comment: Unclear what you have in mind with a broadcast receiver. What kind of broadcast?

Comment: @blackapps i wanted to do like upon receiving the ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED,it gets the apk that was installed from the downloads folder and obtains the uri

Comment: Pretty unclear what you are doing. Why would you receive that broadcast? Tell what you do. Dont let us guess. I never received that broadcast. And does it contain the uri or not? Confusing.

Comment: And how did the apk land in the Download folder?

Comment: I thought the ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED intent is received when a new application is installed on an android device. I want to get the apk that is downloaded and send it to a server elsewhere. I want to send apks that were downloaded from third party sources hence they would usually be in the downloads folder

Comment: You are again confusing as downloading an apk file to Download folder is quite something different as installing an apk from Play Store. If you install from play store the apk will not be in Download folder.

Comment: And who downloaded apks from third party sources? How?

Comment: people who install apps from third party sources like online apk stores or through suspicious links. i am not talking about downloading apps from the playstore. The action_package_added intent works regardless of where the app is downloaded from

Comment: You talk about installing apk's and about downloading apk's. It would be less confusing if you only talked about  one. And i still dont know if your app downloaded the apk to Download folder or another app was used for that.

Comment: the apk that is on the user's downloads folder has not been installed, the file is just there  (in the downloads folder)and usually is obtained from suspicious links. Just assume there are apk files already in the download folder, that is not what i am focusing on. I am focusing on when the user clicks on the file in the download folder and installs it as an Application.

Comment: Well that does not match the text and title of your post. Moreover you could have confirmed that the apk is downloaded not by your app. Strange that a simple question like how the apk landed there is still unanswered.

Comment: If your app did not download the apk then you have no uri. If your app had downloaded the apk you would already have an uri.

Comment: My title is to get the uri of a file in the downloads folder how does that not match..

Comment: my app is not responsible for downloading/installing anything. the app monitors for installations on the device and when there is an installation, it gets the uri of the apk that was installed on the device. My question is if can my application access the storage of an android device to get the uri of the apk that was installed.

Comment: Inspect the intent of that broadcast for an url. I think it will not contain the one you are after as after all its irrelevant. But i dont know. You are the monitoring guy. I never used that broadcast

Comment: The apk is installed on quite a different storage location which has nothing to do with where the file came from.

Comment: It seems like what you _actually_ want is to get the APK file of any app installed from a third-party source.  That's a somewhat different question, and might be possible (I'm not sure) even if the general case you've described is not.